# Preciso fazer um botão para excluir elementos listados em um jTable, como excluir os elementos que estão em um arrayList?

Tags: java

// metodo para Listar

private void exibeDicionario(){
ArrayList meudicionario = cd.retornarTodos();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tblDicionario.setValueAt("", i, 0);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt("", i, 1);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt("", i, 2);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt("", i, 3);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < meudicionario.size() && meudicionario.get(i) != null; i++){
        tblDicionario.setValueAt(meudicionario.get(i).getNumTermo(), i, 0);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt(meudicionario.get(i).getTermo(), i, 1);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt(meudicionario.get(i).getSignificado(), i, 2);
        tblDicionario.setValueAt(meudicionario.get(i).getFonte(), i, 3);
    }
}
```

//Metodo para salvar
private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// Botão salvar
Dicionario d = new Dicionario();

```
    d.setNumTermo(Integer.parseInt(tfdnumTermo.getText()));
    d.setTermo(tfdTermo.getText());
    d.setSignificado(tfdSignificado.getText());
    d.setFonte(tfdFonte.getText());
    
    if (cd.salvar(d)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Termo cadastrado com sucesso!");
        tfdnumTermo.setText("");
        tfdTermo.setText("");
        tfdSignificado.setText("");
        tfdFonte.setText("");
        tfdnumTermo.requestFocus();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao cadastrar o termo!");
    }
}
```

//MInha classe controla dicionario

public class ControlaDicionario {
private ArrayList meudicionario = new ArrayList<>();

```
public boolean salvar (Dicionario d){
    if (d != null){
        meudicionario.add(d);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Dicionario> retornarTodos() {
    return meudicionario;
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isso é uma operação de CRUD básica,geralmente se usa um indentificador para indentificar o objeto a ser excluido, se esta dentro de uma lista, voce poderia iterar essa lista e se achar, excluir.

```
public void excluir (Dicionario d){

   //Ja que todos os seus dicionarios estao em uma lista, voce pode chamar a lista primeiro.
   ArrayList<Dicionario> dicionarios = retornarTodos();

   //Aqui voce esclui usando o metodo remove da class List
   dicionarios.remove(d.id);
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).